# selected boolean value on angular ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The boolean value assigned to the model doesn't pre-select the corresponding option - shows first an empty option instead:

Select:

```
<select data-ng-model="scriptData.privacy" data-ng-options="privacyOption.value as privacyOption.label for privacyOption in privacyOptionsSelect track by privacyOption.value"></select>
```

Options in the controller:

```
$scope.privacyOptionsSelect=[
            {
                label:'Registered users only can view this',
                value: false
            },
            {
                label:'Anyone with the link can view this',
                value: true
            }
        ];
```

`scriptData.privacy` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful when using the `ngOptions` expression with the format:

*select **as** label **for** value **in** array*

together with `track by`. This is because `track by` is applied to the value assigned to your `ngModel`, so if your selection is in the form `privacyOption.value`, the `track by` expression is actually applied to the value. This is the reason it doesn't successfully select the initial value.

To fix this you have two options. You can either just skip `track by`. This would work:

```
<select data-ng-model="scriptData.privacy" 
        data-ng-options="privacyOption.value as privacyOption.label for privacyOption 
            in privacyOptionsSelect"></select>
```

Or you could change the `select as`-expression to select the entire `privacyOption`-object. This would work as well (note the ngModel-directive changed as well):

```
<select data-ng-model="scriptData"
        data-ng-options="privacyOption as privacyOption.label for privacyOption 
            in privacyOptionsSelect track by privacyOption.value"></select>
```

For a full (and probably better) explanation, [I recommend the `ngOptions` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-).

Answer (score 0):

try ng-repeat instead of ng-options by applying the ng-repeat to option elements inside the select.